# Объявление динамического массива С++

Tags: c++

В нижеприведённом коде компилятор подчеркивает второй индекс массива - [ColCount] - и пишет: выражение должно иметь константное значение. Подскажите в чем ошибка и как её исправить?

```
const int RowCount = Height(Root);
const int ColCount = (2 << RowCount) - 1;
char *TreeArray;
TreeArray = new char[RowCount][ColCount];
```

Comment: Так а как насчет `std::vector`?

Comment: Да, действительно наилучший вариант. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> char *TreeArray;
> ```

Это указатель - как бы одномерный массив.

> ```
> TreeArray = new char[RowCount][ColCount];
> ```

А это на одномерный массив ну никак не похоже...

> реализовать динамический массив строк размерностью определяемой в run-time?

```
char **a = new char * [n];

for (size_t q=0; q<n; ++q)
  a[q] = new char [m];

...

for (size_t q=0; q<n; ++q)
  delete [] a[q];

delete [] a;
```

Comment: Спасибо. А не подскажете как можно реализовать динамический массив строк размерностью определяемой в run-time?

Comment: @Georgiy_, примерно написал (надеюсь, не ошибся, не проверял).

Comment: @Qwertiy Конструкция корректная. При определенных ограничениях - см. мой ответ.

Comment: @Harry, поправил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку на собственно вопрос ответ не был дан (о том, что *"выражение должно иметь константное значение"*), поясню...

Компилятор еще не начал разбираться с тем, что именно вы выделяете, какого типа, и как его потом можно будет присвоить - тип у вас объявлен неверно, но это второй вопрос. Пока он смотрит на `new char[RowCount][ColCount]`. А поскольку конструкция

```
new char[A][B]
```

**вполне работоспособна** в C++ (см., например, http://ideone.com/bJeaHF, надо просто понимать, что она делает и какие ограничения на нее наложены), то он начинает с ней разбираться. Что же она делает? Она выделяет память для `A` массивов размера `B`, только вот размер `B` должен быть константой времени компиляции. Тогда ее можно переписать в привычном и более понятном виде:

```
using str = char[B];
new str[A];
```

Это у массивов постоянно встречающееся ограничение :) Вспомните, например, что в функцию можно передать двумерный массив - но только второе измерение должно быть константой **времени компиляции**. Так и тут. Но! Ваши константы, хоть и описаны как `const`, являются константами **времени выполнения** - они не могут изменяться после инициализации, но во время компиляции неизвестны - из-за вычисления `Height(Root)` - это же не `constexpr`- функция от `constexpr`-значения? :)

Вот вам и указывают на этот грустный факт, что во время компиляции значение `ColCount` неизвестно...

Comment: Благодарю. Я считал что размерность динамического массива может вычисляться во время выполнения. Ошибался.

Comment: @Georgiy_ Ну, выходов хватает :), но... Как вы будете к нему обращаться, если выделите? Как компилятору понять, когда вы обратитесь к `a[n][m]`, скажем? Как посчитать? Есть указатель, надо найти смещение `n*ColCount+m`. Как? Где хранить `ColCount`, если есть **только указатель**? А вот если вторая размерность известна при компиляции - то он вполне может посчитать такое смещение...

Comment: А разве при создании динамических объектов не выделяется область памяти в куче? И выделяется не в момент компиляции, а во время выполнения.  И там обращение к элементам уже забота не компилятора, а менеджера кучи.

Comment: @Georgiy_ Обращения к элементам массива выполняются через арифметику указателей. `a[5] == *(a+5)`. У вас при выделении `char[A][B]` выделяется кусок памяти размером `A*B` байт. Все, то у вас есть - указатель. Как вы поручите, имея указатель на начало этого куска `a`, элемент `a[n][m]`? Компилятором ли, менеджером памяти (а он тут при чем?) - неважно. распишите, в какой от начала блока ячейке памяти лежит этот символ?

Comment: n*ColCount+m как вы раньше и писали. Я понимаю, что ошибаюсь, но еще не понимаю почему. Ведь на момент когда выделяется память, значение ColCount уже известно.

Comment: @Georgiy_ Этот код должен генерировать компилятор. С++ не позволяет менять типы во время выполнения, так? А типом `a` в данном случае является указатель на `char[ColCount]`. Который сейчас такой, потом эдакий... Словом, если вам нужен такой массив - заверните его в класс, в котором будет помимо указателя храниться размер, а оператор индекса - выполнять правильные вычисления. А так - у вас просто нет типа времени компиляции. И вся система типов летит к черту. Если типы можно менять во время выполнения - это уже совсем другой язык.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо за объяснение.